# How to test how a program behaves when it can't connect to the internet?

Tags: linux, testing, python-2.7, internet-connection

I'm writing an RSS reader, and I want to gracefully handle situations where the internet connection is unavailable. What's a good way (on linux) to test program behavior in the absence of internet without pulling the cord and/or RF-killing everything?

Comment: depending on the level, you can create an own http server or you mock urllib or the library you use.

Comment: Would that really solve Philip Amy Wright's problem? I'm assuming he wants to differentiate between "no Internet" and "bad URL" when gracefully handling exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As User left in a comment, you could test this by mocking your network access library. At the point the library would normally access the network, you modify the behavior to grab a local file instead. [This post](http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2006/12/mock-testing-examples-and-resources.html) describes the technique more, and includes code samples for Python and urllib.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

From https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=83384:

> ifconfig eth0 down/up? (or other interface instead of eth0)

I can't test this, as I'm at work and need the Internet for stuff currently running, but hopefulyy this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: The posted asked for a solution "without pulling the cord", but this solution does just that-- turns off networking for all purposes.

Comment: I'm assuming Phillip Amy Wright is looking for something that simulates no network without actually reaching behind the box and physically removing a cord. The above commands can be added at the beginning and end of a specific unit test to simulate the application not having Internet for that one test without having to do anything else outside of the unit tests.

Comment: I won't assume it's safe to turn off networking for the entire machine. There may well be other things happening on the machine that need the connection up.